# Installing pyclblast on windows 10 with clblast vcpkg

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, vcpkg

I am trying to install the python package `pyclblast` on Windows 10.

```
pip3 install pyclblast
```

fails with

> src\pyclblast.cpp(700): fatal error C1082: Cannot open include file: 'clblast_c.h': No such file or directory
>
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

I have `clblast` installed via `vcpkg`. The header file is located at `C:\\dev\\vcpkg\\packages\\cblast_x64-windows\\include`. How do I tell `pip3` where to look? I tried

```
pip3 install pyclblast --global-option="/I..."
```

where `...` is the path from above, but that failed with

> invalid command name `/IC:\\...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct way:

```
pip3 install pyclblast --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-IC:\dev\vcpkg\packages\clblast_x64-windows\include;C:\dev\vcpkg\packages\opencl_x64-windows\include" --global-option="-LC:\dev\vcpkg\packages\opencl_x64-windows\lib;C:\dev\vcpkg\packages\clblast_x64-windows\lib"
```

The installation succeeds now, but the module can still not be imported. I will open [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71927063) for that.